Functional has dense kernel if it's not bounded
Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and let $L$ be a non-zero linear functional $D(T) \subseteq X \to \mathbb{C}$. If the domain $D(T)$ is dense and $L$ is not bounded, then the kernel of $L$ is dense. The proof follow the same ideas as in this answer. Nevertheless I would like a book reference for it.
So far I have seen that in Rudin's Functional Analysist the result appears in Theorem 1.18 but the functional is defined on the whole space $X$ so I was looking for a reference where the domain is taken under consideration.
Any suggestions?

Either the linked answer of Rudin's result shows that the kernel is dense in $D(T)$, so it is also dense in $X$?

The kernel is an hyperplan, closed if $L$ is continuous. If not , the only possibility is to be dense because an hyperplan is a  maximal, vectorial subspace. (dimension $n-1$ in finite dimension, codimension $1$ in infinity dimension.

@leoli1 On Rudin's the result is stated in a general sense where $X$ is a topological vector space. Which means that there is a topology such that the "points" are closed sets and that the vector space operations are continuous with respect to that norm. Can I simply use it?

Yes, the topology the norm induces makes the normed space into a topological vector space
